# EF Distinct (IEqualityComparer) Error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-3.0, linq-to-entities

Good Morning!

Given:

```
public class FooClass
{
    public void FooMethod()
    {
        using (var myEntity = new MyEntity)
        {
            var result = myEntity.MyDomainEntity.Where(myDomainEntity => myDomainEntity.MySpecialID > default(int)).Distinct(new FooComparer);
        }
    }

}

public class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyEntity.MyDomainEntity>
{
    public bool Equals(MyEntity.MyDomainEntity x, MyEntity.MyDomainEntity y)
    {
        return x.MySpecialID == y.MySpecialID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyEntity.MyDomainEntity obj)
    {
        return obj.MySpecialID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This will compile, but on runtime I will get an `Linq to Entity could not translate Comparer`-Exception.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you're providing your own comparisons, you'll need to execute the `Distinct` call in .NET code. To make sure that happens, use `AsEnumerable` to turn `IQueryable<T>` into `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var result = myEntity.MyDomainEntity
        .Where(myDomainEntity => myDomainEntity.MySpecialID > default(int))
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Distinct(new FooComparer());
```

Of course at that point you'll be pulling more data across from the database. An alternative is to group the data instead:

```
var result = from entity in myEntity.MyDomainEntity
             where entity.MySpecialID > 0
             group entity by entity.MySpecialID into groups
             select groups.FirstOrDefault();
```

That will get you the first entity encountered with each ID (assuming my query-fu isn't failing me). That's basically what Distinct does anyway, but it's all at the database.

(Note to future readers: calling `First()` makes more sense than `FirstOrDefault()`, but apparently that doesn't work.)

Comment: Is there any chance to do this not in the .NET-Layer? Somehow tell the EF-call to do this in SQL?

Comment: See my edit - use grouping and you'll get the desired behaviour. It would be nice to have "DistinctBy" in the framework (and handled by EF etc) but I think the grouped version will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you! This looks very plausible to me, as you are doing the group on an IQueryable<T>. I will try this later on! PS.: Yes, you got the Distinct-Condition correct :)

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: Rats. Did you try using FirstOrDefault? If that works, I'll fix my answer :)

Comment: Now even IQueryable has extension method with comparer, Then why are they providing this method if it does not work ???

Comment: @hajirazin: Can you give an example? I suspect you're just seeing the overloads inherited from `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: In System.Linq.Queryable there is a method called public static IQueryable<TSource> Distinct<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)

Comment: @hajirazin: That's very interesting. I strongly suspect that most implementations will "know" about particular equality comparers - so you can use it to for (say) string equality comparisons - but it won't support general purpose equality comparisons, as it wouldn't be able to translate them.