# Error on IEqualityComparer<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have been given this solution in one of my question... seems very interesting.. as i am trying and learning to understand LINQ.. I am having this error while implementing this. I dont know whats going wrong here... seeking expert advice.

```
public class CategotiesEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ac_Categories>
{
    public bool Equals(ac_Categories x, ac_Categories y)
    {
        return x.ThumbnailAltText.Trim() == y.ThumbnailAltText.Trim();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ac_Categories obj)
    {
        return obj.ThumbnailAltText.Trim().GetHashCode();
    }
}

var catlist = _db.ac_Categories
.Where(c => c.VisibilityId == 0 && c.ThumbnailAltText != null
    && (!c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("gifts/")
    && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("email/")
    && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("news/")
    && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("promotions/")
    && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("the-knowledge/")))
    .Distinct(new CategotiesEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

> ERROR:LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WebMgr.ac_Categories]
>   Distinct[ac_Categories](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WebMgr.ac_Categories],
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[WebMgr.ac_Categories])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

NOTE:

I am using Database first approach and `ac_Categories` is created using that...

Comment: Your question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1011014/222163

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass an `IEqualityComparer` comparer into a call to an EF query or likely most `IQueryable` collections. `IQueryable` are expression trees, that expression tree gets converted into an underlying query (such as SQL with EF).  As such it can't execute your code in SQL.

A normal `Distinct()` call will work just fine if you want to filter out duplicate identical records as it will perform a SQL distinct. If you it to apply your equality comparer you would have to pull the data into memory then apply your distinct.

Comment: yes... i got it .... I have to use AsEnumerable()

Comment: Yes but be aware that this will only execut the WHERE in SQL, the distinct will be performed in memory.  Depending on the size of your dataset a group by might be quicker.